# Set specific time on android

Tags: android

On android,  Is there any way to freeze / stop the system clock at a specific time so he just don't run forward but just stay permanent at that specific time ? Also is there any way after that to just disable him or hide it from the task bar ? Ps:(I tried some launchers that have the hiding clock option and some exposed tweaks but they did not work for me ) . 
I use android 4.4.4
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for a source code solution or a working launcher?

Comment: It doesn't matter, something that can i use for this situation, an app or a launcher , or source code , but in the case of code I will need help on implementing the code. Thank you !